# skip release in Google play Developer Console

Tags: google-developers-console

In the releases overview of my app in the Developer Console of Google play I can see the following Releases prepared for publishing:

[image]

I have 2 releases ready to publish, but I only want to publish the latest (GREEN) and skip the 3.15 Release, which is marked as RED.

How can this be done?

Comment: any updates on this?